# Distance of point on ellipse from origin

Tags: euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

I need to determine distance to a point on an ellipse.

center point is 0,0 (Cartesian coordinates).

I have a,b. for example, b (y radius) is .66, a (x radius) is .87

I have angle from positive X axis (0 quadrant), 45 or 30 degrees for example.

wouldn't the distance (ds) to the point simply be:

d (difference) = abs (a-b). example: abs(.66-.87) = .21

rmin (minimum radius) = smallest of a and b.

r (ratio) =  angle/90. examples: .5 for 45/90, or .33 for 30/90.

formula: ds = rmin + (d * r)
or distance = minimum radius plus (difference * ratio)

if 45 degrees = .66 + (.5 * .21) = .765. similarly, .73 for 30 degrees

(adjustments would have to be made for other quadrants). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take the equation $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$ use a cartesian to polar conversion $x=r \cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin \theta$ and solve for $r$

$$ \frac{ r^2 \cos^2 \theta}{a^2} + \frac{ r^2 \sin^2 \theta}{b^2} = 1 $$

$$ \boxed{ r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \frac{\cos^2\theta}{a^2} + \frac{\sin^2\theta}{b^2} } } } $$

Plug in your angle $\theta=30°$ and the semi-radii $a=0.87$ and $b=0.66$ to get for example $r =\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.990883868410622+0.573921028466483
}} = 0.799410598404111 $

Comment: Thanks, ja72.  this is a beautiful solution, I appreciate it!

Comment: Hi ja72. you use cos and sin of the angle.  can you explain or point me to how these are calculated.  This is for a program, so not using a calculator. So I have to derive these values in code.

Comment: Every programming language has `Cos(x)` and `Sin(x)` functions, that accept angles in radians `x = π/180 * degrees`. The $\sin^2(x)$ is just the square of the function `Sin(x)*Sin(x)`.

Comment: Thanks again, makes sense.

Comment: I have used the formula in my program and it works. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can write the ellipse as such: $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1 \iff$

$$\frac{(rcosθ)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(rsinθ)^2}{b^2}=1$$

Since you know $a,b$ and $θ$ of your point, you can solve for $r$ and that is the distance of the point from the origin.

(For better formatting you may want to have look here:
[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference))

Comment: Thanks, Michael. my trig rusty, can I impose on you to create the equation? i.e., r = ...

Comment: $$r=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{(bcosθ)^2+(asinθ)^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks, Michael. your equation is much more elegant than mine! I'm certain this will help others in the future!

Comment: Hi Michael, you use cos and sin of the angle.  can you explain or point me to how these are calculated.  This is for a program, so not using a calculator. So I have to derive these values in code.  thanks.

Comment: @zpanama Your software probably has these functions already. cos(), and sin() will probably work if you try it. What program are you using?

Comment: using visual studio 2015.  you are correct I can use cos() and sin() with just the angle. I asked before I finished checking, my bad. At the same time, I really appreciate you verifying this and I know will make it clearer for other programmers with rusty trig.